# Is there an application which highlights findstr matching characters

Tags: regex, findstr

I'm working with a list of files, containing date/time stamps.

Those have two possible formats:

```
YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
```

I'd like to know what are the entries, starting today, half past twelve.

In order to do this, I've written following regular expression:

```
"2017[-/]09[-/]12 12:3[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"
```

Meaning the following:

- Between year, month and day we might have two possible characters,
  hence `[-/]`
- The timestamp should look like "12:3x:xx" (somewhere
  after 12:30, but not more than 10 minutes later), so I've used `[0-9]`.
- the semicolons are to be treated as normal characters, but as they are not embedded inside brackets `[` or `]`, I've decided simply to write them without escape character (is there an escape character for `findstr`, by the way?).

To my surprise the following entries seem to fit:

```
2017/09/12 13:14:36.777|__logfile_|13240|17508|CClass::Function|CRU|-1|** Releasing critical section m_Busy
2017/09/12 13:14:36.777|__logfile_|13240|17508|CClass::Function|CRU|-1|** Done with Function
```

I have no clue which characters obey the regular expression I've written, and obviously I prefer not to write a StackOverflow post at every issue I have with `findstr`, therefore I'd like to know: is there somewhere a tool which can verify `findstr` regular expressions and highlights the results (so that I can progressively learning how to correct my expressions)?

Comment: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Meanwhile I've solved the issue by adding a "%"-sign at the beginning of my regular expression (meaning "beginning of line"), but I'm still interested in the regular expression tester tool, I'd like to know what I am doing wrong and how I can test my expressions in future.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Domnique I'm not sure where the disconnect is.  I'm using your regex pattern copied verbatim in regexr and I'm getting the expected results with the data set you supplied.  Neither of those 2 strings match the pattern, but when I change the time from `13:14` to `12:31` it matches.  Try playing around with the tool some more to increase your familiarity and maybe you will stumble on the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex works for me. You didn't say how you were calling `findstr`

You need the `/R` (regex) and `/C` (literal string) flags:

```
findstr /R /C:"2017[-/]09[-/]12 12:3[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" logfile.txt
```